# useEffect empty dependency array inside a component which gets rendered inside useCallback has no meaning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a payment page, the user clicks on the button "PAY", then a modal opens, it shows loading..., then it either renders the "payment success" component or the "payment failed" component.

When it renders any of the both, it plays a sound effect,

- on success, it plays the sound effect of CheckTennnn! ✅ "payment success".
- on fail, it plays the sound effect of EEeerr.. ❌ "payment failed".

The way I am implementing it is by having a useCallback which decides which view to render inside the modal, [success, or the fail view].

```
export default ProcessPaymentModal({ isSuccess, isError, isLoading }){
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0)
    
    useEffect(()=> { 
        const intervalId = setInterval(()=> setTimer((previousState)=> previousState + 1), 1000)
        return ()=> clearInterval(intervalId)
    })

    const View = useCallback(()=>{
      switch(true){
         case isSuccess:
           return <PaymentSuccessView timer={timer}/>
         case isError:
           return <PaymentFailView timer={timer}/>
         case isLoading:
           return <LoadingView />
      }
    }, [timer, isSuccess, isError, isLoading])

    return (
       <React.Fragment>
          some content
          <View />
       </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

And inside these fail or success components, I have that useEffect which plays the audio only once, on mount (and it must only play the sound once).

```
export default function PaymentSuccessView({ timer }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const soundEffect = new Audio('../media/checktennn.mp3')
    soundEffect.play()
  }, []);
  return <button> OK ({timer}) </button>;
}
```

Here's a stack blitz instance, a code sandbox to test, ([Click me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1f6e8x?file=src/components/Parent.jsx))

However, the problem is that it keeps playing the sound every time the timer changes,

- CheckTennnn! ✅
- CheckTennnn! ✅
- CheckTennnn! ✅

Like this, you know.

Even though I have the dependency array empty in the `<PaymentSuccessView />` component, which means this `useEffect` function must only run once. On mount.

Comment: Maybe, the problem is `View` is always different component as lont as its value depends on `timer`. You change `timer`, then you get new `View` component which will lead any component inside to render "newly" leading to its mount. You could at least remove usage of `useCallback` here and just render what you need like `if (isSuccess) return <PaymentSuccessView timer={timer}/>` etc. without usage of new Component implementation

Comment: If `timer` changes then the component will get re-rendered right. What do you expect to happen? From what i see in your stackblitz timer keeps on increasing, so definitely the useCallback or even if you use useMemo will keep on recomputing

Comment: it's unclear why you are using `useCallback`

Comment: @TusharShahi, yes,  I thought even when the `useCallback` gets called multiple times, the `PaymentSuccessView`'s useEffect will run only once because of its empty dependency array.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava, the state of the request (I'm using [redux toolkit query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview)) is being passed to the `<ProcessPaymentModal />`, component, which is the component responsible for showing the Success/Fail/Loading components based on the props its given. For the `<ProcessPaymentModal />` (based on my what I currently know) to notice that these arguments are getting changed, it should use something like `useEffect` or `useCallback`, to render, or React will complain that you're updating the state too quickly while other state is updating.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you use `useCallback` to define Component. As long as its value  depends on current `timer`, every time `timer` changes, value of `View` component changes and new element of new type will be attached to React DOM. So, every component used inside new `View` will be mounted leading to `console.log`.

To solve the problem, you should define component `View` separately to not change its value each time `timer` changes or refactor code of modal as follows:

```
export default ProcessPaymentModal({ isSuccess, isError, isLoading }){
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0)
    
    useEffect(()=> { 
        const intervalId = setInterval(()=> setTimer((previousState)=> previousState + 1), 1000)
        return ()=> clearInterval(intervalId)
    })

    if (isSuccess) {
        return <PaymentSuccessView timer={timer}/>
    }
    if (isError) {
        return <PaymentFailView timer={timer}/>
    }
    return <LoadingView />;
}
```

Also, fixed stackblitz example to try:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f8atrq?file=src/components/Parent.jsx

*You will see console messages twice as long as `<Strict>` component was used*

Comment: Yes, nice, I'll try that out, it would be nicer if it was a switch case block. Good solution though

Comment: "_You will see console messages twice as long as <Strict> component was used_", yes of course

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution to this, with the using of `useCallback`,

You can pass props to the `<View />` component directly as follows:

```
export default ProcessPaymentModal({ isSuccess, isError, isLoading }){
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0)
    
    useEffect(()=> { 
        const intervalId = setInterval(()=> setTimer((previousState)=> previousState + 1), 1000)
        return ()=> clearInterval(intervalId)
    })

    const View = useCallback(({ timer })=>{
      switch(true){
         case isSuccess:
           return <PaymentSuccessView timer={timer} />
         case isError:
           return <PaymentFailView timer={timer} />
         case isLoading:
           return <LoadingView />
      }
    }, [isSuccess, isError, isLoading]) // no need to have timer in the array anymore

    return (
       <React.Fragment>
          some content
          <View timer={timer} />
       </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Forked stack blitz example, a sandbox, ([click me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t8pqau?file=src/components/Parent.jsx))

Comment: Will probably break when `isSuccess == true`, `isLoading == false`. Then, when `ProcessPaymentModal` updated its properties to `isSuccess == true`, `isLoading == true`, you will still see  `PaymentSuccessView` but it will be mounted again and you will see console log. `View` will just be the other component. The reason is idea of defining component using `useCallback` with dependencies is just incorrect and will lead to bugs. Components should be constant functions which could apply properties through argument. You should not define components depending on these properties.

Comment: To avoid the problem, you could use `useCallback` without dependencies, but this makes no sense. Instead of this, you could also just define component `View` outside of `ProcessPaymentModal`

Comment: "_you could also just define component View outside of ProcessPaymentModal_", yes I believe this is the best solution to the problem, since I can't simply `return` the view, I have to assign it to a variable, because the "view" is not the only thing returned, there is _"some content"_ as well, see my codes, I updated them

Comment: Still don't get why you need `View` component declaration inside other component. You can still define separate `View` component outside of `ProcessPaymentModal` and pass required properties. Return statement would be almost the same as in your current code